# VBA - Use wildcards to find correct string

Tags: vba, wildcard, ms-word, word-2010

I have a macro that use the Find function to find the string that starts with number / number number etc.. Example:
1/2313-gergre....
4/5385-gewsgergeo....

I tried following without success:

```
    StartString = "#/#"
    With Rng.Find
    .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute(findText:=StartString, Forward:=False) = True
            MsgBox ("Found")

        Loop
    End With
```

It works if I use *, but I only want to accept numbers..

Comment: Word does not use the rules for the `Like` operator (see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/add-power-to-word-searches-with-regular-expressions-HA001087305.aspx)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
StartString = "[0-9]/[0-9]"
    With myRange.Find
    .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute(findText:=StartString, Forward:=False) = True
            MsgBox ("Found")

        Loop
    End With
```

Here's an [link](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm) with other wildcard options